# How to put scroll function in PDF.js

Tags: javascript, android, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js to view a PDF file in my Android application. I'm using [this](https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js) as my reference to do so. I enable as well the zoom function. What I wanted to do is, instead of using the `onOptionsItemSelected` where it has the function to go to next page or go back to the previous page I want to go to the next page while I scroll down like in the adobe reader app or just by swiping right or left.

I tried using `setOnTouchListener` on my WebView but it seems I'm having a conflict on my zoom.

Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:onNextPage()");
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        case R.id.action_previous:
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:onPrevPage()");
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to go to the next page when swiping to left and right but encountered another error when the web view is zoomed. So instead of detecting if the web view is full screen or not, i choose to use the other way around and just put two buttons for switching to other pages. And use `webView.loadUrl("javascript:onNextPage()");` and `webView.loadUrl("javascript:onPrevPage()");` for the two buttons.